# How to replace <div> with another <div> on-click of link within the divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a div in a page. Lets call it `div1`.
The div contains a link, say 'Link1'. I want to click `Link1` and replace `div1` with `div2`, which has a `Link2`; `Link2` onclick replaces `div2` with `div1`. 
Need to accomplish this using javascript/angularjs/html/css.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Comment: Need more details what you do

Answer (score 1):

Since you had no description of requirements, I am answering this question in the most general way possible.

My solution is done using vanilla Javascript to manipulate the DOM via event Listeners. You may translate my method in anyway you may like.

You can accomplish this by toggling the CSS display property of the other div.

Run the following and note the more important part is the Javascript:

```js
let div1 = document.getElementById('div1')
let div2 = document.getElementById('div2')
let link1 = document.getElementById('link1')
let link2 = document.getElementById('link2')

link1.addEventListener("click", function () {
  div1.style.display = "none"
  div2.style.display = "block"
})

link2.addEventListener("click", function () {
  div2.style.display = "none"
  div1.style.display = "block"
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

#div2 { 
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
}

#div1 {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"> 
  <a id="link1" href="#">Link 1</a>
</div>
<div id="div2"> 
  <a id="link2" href="#">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a compatibility note `let` will fail in all versions of [IE but IE 11](http://caniuse.com/#feat=let)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it with angularJS is to use ng-if and ng-click on the anchor tags, you have to have href in there if you want it to show as a link (here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/AKMorris/kg0ddyax/):

```
<div>
   <div ng-if="show1==true">
     <a href ng-click="show()">Show 2</a>
   </div>
   <div ng-if="show2==true">
     <a href ng-click="show()">Show 1</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

And in script section:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.show1 = true;
    $scope.show2 = false;
    $scope.show = function()
    {
            if ($scope.show1 == true)
        {
                $scope.show1 = false;
            $scope.show2 = true;
        }
        else
        {
                $scope.show2 = false;
            $scope.show1 = true;
        }
    }
});
```

This is just one way to do it with angularJS.

Answer (score 0):

this will also do the trick, simple toggle function with ng-if and ng-click.
https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/1393/

html:

```
   <div ng-app="myModule">
      <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
          <div ng-if="showDiv1" ng-click="toggleDivs()">div1</div>
          <div ng-if="!showDiv1" ng-click="toggleDivs()">div2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

angular module and controller

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.showDiv1 = true;
   $scope.toggleDivs = function(){
        $scope.showDiv1 = !$scope.showDiv1
   }

});
```